# Why would Part::partw appear in DSolve expression in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve an differential equation:

`DSolve[{0.02*x^2*y''[x] - y'[x] - y[x] == 0}, y[x], x]`

But I got warnings:

`Part::partw: Part 2 of {1} does not exist.`

How do I understand this warning? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce this in V7.0.1, but not in V8.0.1, so it looks like a bug that got fixed at some point.  The ultimate answers in both versions are the same.

Comment: I am using v7. So I got the warning. :)